# Getting SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" for rabbitmq

Tags: java, xml, maven, rabbitmq

I am trying to learn rabbitmq with it's JAVA APIs.

### Producer

```java
package org.rabbitmq.org.rabbitmq.helloworld;
import  com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Producer {
    private static final String  QUEUE_NAME="hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("http://localhost:15672");

        try(Connection conn = factory.newConnection(); Channel channel = conn.createChannel()){
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME,false,false,false,null);
            String msg = "Hi, i am Rahul";
            System.out.println("Pushed message -> "+msg);
        }
    }
}
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Java</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
      <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Upon running the `Producer.java` i am getting the following error.

```java
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: http://localhost:15672: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1638)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:997)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1628)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1494)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:160)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1294)
    at org.rabbitmq.org.rabbitmq.helloworld.Producer.main(Producer.java:13)
```

Note : My rabbitmq server is running on port 15672. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth pointing out that the message from SLF4J isn't the real problem here. That's just a warning saying that SLF4J couldn't find a suitable logging library to use to write logs.

The real problem here is the `UnknownHostException`. I believe the problem is caused by this line:

```java
        factory.setHost("http://localhost:15672");
```

You need to pass the host name to `factory.setHost`, but you are passing a URL instead, and this URL contains a protocol (`http`) and a port number (`15672`) as well as the host name (`localhost`).

Connections to RabbitMQ appear not to use the HTTP protocol, so the `http://` part is incorrect. Also, it seems the port number is passed using a separate method call rather than as part of the hostname.

Try the following instead:

```java
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(15672);
```

I have to admit that I've never used RabbitMQ before, so I can't guarantee that the code above works. I've based my answer on the ['Connecting to RabbitMQ' section of the RabbitMQ API guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#connecting).

Comment: The issue is resolved when i added changes suggested  by and changed port form `15672 -> 5672`.

Comment: Not sure why `15672` port number is not working...

Comment: Not having a proper slf4j backend may cause important logs not to be seen

Comment: @Rahul: I note from the page I linked to that port 5672 is the default. So presumably the server hasn't been configured to use a port other than the default.

Comment: `http://localhost:15672/` is available in browser but `http://localhost:5672` is not available in browser.

Comment: @Rahul: in that case it seems RabbitMQ runs a management console over HTTP on port 15672 but the message queue itself runs using some other protocol on port 5672.

Comment: I think too, but will confirm